# Печать Word файла с диалоговым окном "печать" с помощью C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, печать, принтер, office-interop

Нужно по нажатии кнопки открыть диалоговое окно для печати word документа.
Доступен метод `word.printout();`, но при его вызове ничего не происходит. Я вообще мало понимаю в печати из word приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
    wordApp.Visible = true;            
    string file = "c:\\test\\test.doc";

    var docs = wordApp.Documents;
    var doc = docs.Open(FileName:file);
    doc.Activate();

    int dialogResult = wordApp.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFilePrint].Show();
}
```

Источник: [Ответ McAden на stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/878438/8674428)